# Does the law of diminishing returns apply to language practice?

Tags: learning-methods, reference-request

Have there been any studies supporting the idea that the longer you practice a language each session, the less benefit you yield from it? I've always thought this was true, and thus I always tend to practice in short but frequent sessions.

My question doesn't refer to a specific language; a study supporting this effect on learners of any language is sufficient.

Comment: I don't have any evidence to support this except my own experience, but I strongly believe the opposite pattern is true when it comes to language learning. I have attempted to describe this phenomenon in my question here about "momentum"

Comment: @Flimzy https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/2382/momentum-and-hours-per-week

Answer (score 2):

Short and frequent is good for any type of learning, the frequency which is more important than the duration. It's during the "in-between" times (diffuse mode) that your brain gets a chance to reformulate itself.

It is explained very nicely in this video

> [Learning how to learn | Barbara Oakley | TEDxOaklandUniversity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O96fE1E-rf8)